# History file was rewritten

Tags: ssh, bashrc, history

I had more then 5K records in my history file on Ubuntu 22.04. But for 5 last months I used  my computer only by ssh and now I found that .bash_history file was rewritten with only ssh sessions. And I lost my history. Can it be because I used `history -a` command.
My .bashrc set to unlimited history:

```
 HISTSIZE=-1
HISTFILESIZE=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunatly, Pycharm made its own backup.
I found it here
~/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/terminal/history